# Changing GLSL shader color based on particle position

Tags: opengl, shader

I am currently working on a particle system in which each particle is a point. I am using shaders to color the particles. I would like the particle to change colors based on its position. However, when I try to include an extra vector variable in my fragment and vertex shaders, my shaders do not compile.

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec3 normal; 
varying vec3 vertex_to_light_vector;
varying vec3 vertex_to_eye_vector;
//out vec3 color;
//varying float red;
//varying float green;
//varying float blue;

//black body radiation color map

void main ()
{
    const vec4 AmbientColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    const vec4 DiffuseColor = vec4(0.0, 0.1,0.3, 0.1);
    const vec4 SpecularColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1);
    vec3 normalized_normal = normalize(normal);
    vec3 normalized_vertex_to_light_vector = normalize(vertex_to_light_vector);
    vec3 normalized_vertex_to_eye_vector = normalize(vertex_to_eye_vector);
    vec3 bisector = normalize(vertex_to_light_vector + vertex_to_eye_vector);

    float DiffuseTerm = clamp(max(0.0, dot(normalized_normal, normalized_vertex_to_light_vector)), 0.0, 1.0);
    float SpecularTerm = clamp(max(0.0, dot(normalized_normal, bisector)), 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_FragColor = DiffuseColor * DiffuseTerm;
    //+ SpecularColor * pow(SpecularTerm, 80.0);

}
```

Vertex shader:

```
varying vec3 normal; 
varying vec3 vertex_to_light_vector;
varying vec3 vertex_to_eye_vector;
//out vec3 color;
//varying float red;
//varying float green;
//varying float blue;
//varying vec2 texture_coordinate;
//uniform sample2D my_color_texture;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; //gettingfinal position in projection space

    if (gl_Position[0] > 0.5){
//        color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
//        red =1.0;
//        green = 0.0;
//        blue = 0.0;
    }
    else {
//        color = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
//        color[0] = 0.0;
//        color[1] = 0.0;
//        color[2] = 1.0;
//        red = 0.0;
//        green = 0.0;
//        blue = 1.0;
    }

    normal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    vec4 vertex_in_modelView_space = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    vertex_to_light_vector = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position - vertex_in_modelView_space); 

    vertex_to_eye_vector = vec3(-vertex_in_modelView_space);

    //texture_coordinate = vec2(gl_MultiTexCoord0);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since your shader does not contain a `#version` directive on the first line, a compliant GLSL compiler is supposed to treat your shader as [GLSL 1.1](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.10.59.pdf). This creates a serious problem with your `color` output, because the `in` and `out` qualifiers were not valid for varying declarations prior to [OpenGL 3.0](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec30.20080923.pdf) ([GLSL 1.3](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.30.10.pdf)).

More than likely what is actually happening is that the compiler is encountering `out` and this is generating a parse error. Use `varying` instead, since these GLSL shaders are implicitly `#version 110`.

Even if the shaders were written using `#version 130`, you have another issue that will prevent successful I/O between the vertex shader and fragment shader after linking. Vertex shader ***outputs*** are fragment shader ***inputs***, thus your `color` variable would need to be declared: `out vec3 color` in the vertex shader and `in vec3 color` in the fragment shader. But again, this only applies to *modern* OpenGL shaders written against the OpenGL 3.0 GLSL spec. (GLSL 130) or newer.

For future reference, if you were to call [`glGetShaderInfoLog (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) after attempting to compile your shaders, it would inform you of the parse error. Likewise, [`glGetProgramInfoLog (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml) will give you any linker errors after you call [`glLinkProgram (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLinkProgram.xml) or [`glValidateProgram (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glValidateProgram.xml).